# Set frequency to audio file

Tags: java, audio

I am newbie to audio conversion and i am doing research to converting normal audio file into less frequency or inaudible sound. Is there any way in java or any other tool to convert less inaudible sate of audio file. i searched quit a while, but still dint get any proper answers. Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of audio are you talking about? a midi file/notes? an audio file like a wav/mp3?

Comment: A normal audio file (mp3, wav etc.,)

Comment: What do you want to exactly do, change the gain/pitch/etc of the input sound or just the volume? Also do you want to do this "real time" or just change it and save the new audio?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite complex problem called "pitch shifting". It requires advanced DSP algorithms. This is not available as part of the core Java Sound API and is unlikely to ever become so.

Comment: @Dark_Knight is right, from my experience this is a rather complex/hard to do specially if you are new,  similar algorithms are used in guitar digital pedals to change real-time the sound of the input device to generate several effects.